# {} を含む文字列を {} の前後でリストに分割し、{} 自体は空文字とする方法

Tags: python

```
sample = "アイス{}{}ー"
```

という文があるとします。
この中の `{}` を、分割をす‌​るパワーを持つもの、デ‌​ィヴィジョナー・分割者（独自用語です）と考えます。
（デリミタというのは辞書で調べると、データの区切りにつけるマークということで、‌​たとえば、この場合だと、コンマ(`,`)だと‌​考えました。なので、分割をす‌​るパワーを持つものを、`{}`として、デ‌​ィヴィジョナーとしたつもりです）

```
sample.split("{}")
```

とすると、
通常の結果は、

```
["アイス","","ー"]
```

となります。
これを、

```
["アイス","","","ー"]
```

と出力する方法はありますか？

Comment: デリミターが２個なら、出力されるリストの要素が３つになるのは当然なのですが、要素が４つとはどのようなロジックですか？

Comment: @Haru たとえば入力が `"{}a{}"` のときや `"b{}c"` のときはどのように出力されてほしいですか？

Comment: @nekketsuu　[" ","a"," "],["b"," ","c"]となってほしいです。

Comment: デリミタと言いつつも`{}`は空の要素をくくる役割も持たせているように見えますが違いますか？

Comment: 私の知識の根元が間違えているんでしょうか。デリミタっていうのは辞書で調べると、データの区切りにつけるマークということで、たとえば、この場合だと、コンマ(,)だと考えていてしまいました。なので、分割をするパワーを持つものを、"{}"として、ディヴィジョナー（分割者）としたつもりでした。（以前の質問に書いていますが消してしまいました。バッジをもらえました。）皆様には大変混乱をさせて申し訳ありませんが、私はどうやら理解力（基礎力？）が不足しているようです。皆様の反応と自分の意図を照らし合わせると、どうもすれ違っているような気がいたします。そして私に何らかの原因があるように思っています。もう一度振り返って言い方を変えると、{}の部分を、例えばsplitで分割したときに、strがlistになるうえ、文字が分割されますよね？その効果も受け取りたい上に、{}の部分が" "として、リストの一要素になってほしいのです。そういう何らかの方法は無いのかなと思って質問してみました。

Comment: 欲しいのは `["アイス", "", "", "", "ー"]` じゃないでしょうか（ `アイス`→「ここで分割」→`{}` と `{}` に挟まれた空文字列→「ここで分割」→`ー`）．

Comment: @Yosh　いいえ。欲しいものにぶれはないです。上のコメントで書いたような結果が欲しいです。Yoshさんの場合、私の意図したものより、" "が一つ多いことになります。

Comment: なるほど `{}a{}`→ `["", "a", ""]` も同じ形ですね．失礼しました．（たぶん `split` に引きずられて誤解してしまいました）．『「普通の文字列の塊+」か「`{}`」のどっちか』が並んでるのを読み取ってリストにしたい感じですね

Comment: `{}`をデリミタとして見るより、いっそ`{}`でくくられた文字列ごとに要素に分割→`{アイス}{}{}{ー}`の方が分かりやすいと思いますが、これではNGでしょうか。

Comment: @cubick　`re.compile("\{(.*?)\}")`で、`findall`メソッドを使うと、望み通りの結果が出力できました。しかし、{アイス}と{ー}ではないということを前提にしています。なるほど。そういう事を考えていただいているとはそこまで頭が回りませんでした。確かに質問には書いていません。これまでの皆さんの答えを参考にさせていただくと、どうやら元の要素に変更を加えず、メソッドのみを駆使して結果にたどり着くには、どうやらPythonの根幹部分や世界の法則を変える必要があり、私の要求に無理があるようです。お手を煩わせまして申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: 質問で使用されている、delimiter は「デ‌​ィヴィジョナー（分割者）」のタイポということですか？

Comment: 自分の意図に引き直すとそんな感じになってしまうかと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` が空文字を生成するということは、`{` と `}` は、文字列を囲むための構文であると考えられます（こういった構文の一部は、文脈によって、クォートと呼ばれることがあります）。
以下はそれを前提とします。
つまり、`{abc}` は `abc` になります。

#### 正規表現

正規表現だと、例えばこのような表現が考えられます。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
quoted = "アイス{}{}ー"

words = re.findall("[^{}]+|(?<={)[^{}]*(?=})", quoted)
print(words)
```

出力:

```
['アイス', '', '', 'ー']
```

[`re.X`フラグ](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/re.html#re.X)で説明を付けたのが以下です。

```
words = re.findall(
    """
        # 囲われていない部分
        [^{}]+
    |
        # { } で囲われている部分
            # { は結果に含めない
            (?<={)
                # 中身
                [^{}]*
            # } は結果に含めない
            (?=})
    """,
    quoted,
    flags=re.X
)
```

#### 正規表現の補助的な使用

将来のことを考えると、正規表現の使用は控えめにするべきです。

```
words = re.findall("[^ {} ]+  |  [ {} ]", quoted, flags=re.X)
print("words:", words)

prev = None
result = []
for w in words:
    if w not in "{}":
        result.append(w)
    elif prev == "{" and w == "}":
        result.append("")
    prev = w
print("result:", result)
```

出力:

```
words: ['アイス', '{', '}', '{', '}', 'ー']
result: ['アイス', '', '', 'ー']
```

Answer (score 2):

せっかくなので。

冒頭と末尾に`{}`が来ないことが保証できるなら `{}` を一つ増やしてsplitすることに等しいですよね。
一つ**足りないと思っている**のですから、一つ**増やせばいい**と考えるのは自然ではないでしょうか。

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = "アイス{}{}ー"
>>> re.sub('(\{\})+', lambda m: '{}' * (len(m.group(0)) // 2 + 1), sample).split('{}')
['アイス', '', '', 'ー']
```

冒頭と末尾に`{}`にくる時の挙動が望み通りではないでしょうから、あとから削除すればいいかと。

```
>>> l = re.sub('(\{\})+', lambda m: '{}' * (len(m.group(0)) // 2 + 1), "{}a{}").split('{}')
>>> if l[0] == '':
...     l = l[1:]
...
>>> if l[-1] == '':
...     l = l[:-1]
...
>>> l
['', 'a', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

こうでしょうか

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = "アイス{}{}ー"
>>> re.split('{}', sample)
['アイス', '', 'ー']

>>> re.split('({})', sample)
['アイス', '{}', '', '{}', 'ー']

>>> [s for s in re.split('({})', sample) if s]
['アイス', '{}', '{}', 'ー']

>>> delimiter = "{}"
>>> [s for s in re.split('(%s)' % delimiter, sample) if s]
['アイス', '{}', '{}', 'ー']

>>> [
...     s if s != delimiter else ''
...     for s in re.split('(%s)' % delimiter, sample)
...     if s
... ]
['アイス', '', '', 'ー']

>>> [s if s != delimiter else '' for s in re.split('(%s)' % delimiter, '{}a{}') if s]
['', 'a', '']

>>> [s if s != delimiter else '' for s in re.split('(%s)' % delimiter, 'b{}c') if s]
['b', '', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

逆方向に考えてみましょう。データが複数個あって、それを表現する方法として「デリミタで区切った文字列」を生成するのだと考えてみてください。

"A","B","C","D"という四つのデータがあって、それをデリミタを","で文字列化すると"A,B,C,D"という文字列になります。そこでデリミタを"{}"にする、と規定した場合、文字列は"A{}B{}C{}D"になります。逆方向の変換ではプログラムは"{}"に遭遇したらその前後を切り出すという処理をしますので、この文字列をデリミタ"{}"で区切れば"A","B","C","D"というデータを取り出すことができますよね。

しかし、Haruさんがやりたいことの一つは"{}"が出現したら空文字列として切り出してほしい、だと思います。ですが、これだけだと、空文字列ではないデータを区切ることができません。

もう一度"{}a{}"について考えてみましょう。これは"","a",""に切り出せます、つまり、Haruさんの想定しているルールで、データ"","a",""を表現すれば、"{}a{}"となります。

しかし、"","a","b",""というデータをその表現形式に落とし込むことはできません。なぜなら、"a"と"b"の境界を表現する方法がないからです。これを文字列化するなら"{}a（何か"{}"ではない別の区切り文字）b{}"になります。必ず「何か"{}"ではない別の区切り文字」が必要になります。そしてそれこそが本来の「デリミタ」です。

例えば、「デリミタは","、ただし、空文字列は{}で表現し、空文字列と空ではないデータの区切りでは","を省略してもよい」というようなルールを決めれば（そんなルールを採用することがあるかどうかは別として）、"","a","b",""は"{}a,b{}"という文字列にできます。

あるいは、元々のデータ自体が空文字列同士が連続することはあっても、空文字列ではないデータが連続することはないのかも知れません。そうであれば、"","a","b",""というデータ自体が不正なので、これをどのような文字列に落とし込むかを悩む必要はありません。その場合はデリミタという概念は捨てて、「データを連続で文字列化する、ただし空文字列は"{}"で表わす」というルールを定めればいいのです。こうするとデリミタがそもそも不要になります。（そんなデータを出力するシステムがあるかどうかは別として。）